# How to override / add custom html in Sonata Admin Login Form

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony6

Hello Symfony developers, I'm trying to override / add the custom html to the default Sonata Admin login form:

[image]

I tried to find the answer, but I think I can't found it because the threads I found are very old and they are not for my version of Symfony & Sonata Admin Bundle

My versions:
Sonata Admin Bundle 4.27.0
Symfony 6.3.4

The template that I want to override is here:
/home/offices/copyrent.crm.app/vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/src/Resources/views/Admin/Security/login.html.twig

When I place it in:
/home/offices/copyrent.crm.app/templates/bundles/SonataUserBundle/src/Resources/views/Admin/Security/login.html.twig

It doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original template file path:

```
<project-dir>/vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/src/Resources/views/Admin/Security/login.html.twig
```

Is now placed in:

```
<project-dir>/templates/bundles/SonataUserBundle/Admin/Security/login.html.twig
```

In the login.html.twig template:

```
{% extends "@!SonataUser/Admin/Security/login.html.twig" %}
{% block sonata_wrapper %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

**Applicable to:**
Sonata Admin Bundle 4.27.x
Symfony 6.3.x